# Datatables Stop running this script error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jsf-2, datatables

Is there any way to get rid of the Stop running this script error while using jQuery.dataTables.js?
This occurs only in IE when I have more than 100 entries in the data table.
I disabled all kinds of sorting but I still get the error.

Server side processing is not an option for me as the solution should be as simple as possible.

Is there any plugin other than jQuery datatables which can render a table. I'm using JSF 2.0

Comment: jQuery Datatables does not render a `<h:dataTable>`. It just renders a `<table>`, exactly like as JSF `<h:dataTable>` does. If you're looking for a pure JSF solution, head to a 3rd party component library. For example, PrimeFaces: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableHome.jsf

Comment: Interesting. This one looks better. I'll see if it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the best discussion for the issue of DataTables bringing IE to a halt has taken place, and indeed is still going forward, at the jQuery DataTables forum. 
http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4739/beating-the-ie-dead-horse/p1

That being said, have you explored the `bDeferRender` option?
http://datatables.net/ref#bDeferRender

> "Deferred rendering can provide DataTables with a huge speed boost when you are using an Ajax **or JS** [*emphasis added*] data source for the table."

Comment: I tried the bDeferRender option but it doesn't work. I used the latest stable version of datatables(1.8.2) and it worked but only for about 300 entries more than which I still get the error.